# Finding a plane with a line and a another plane

Tags: calculus

> Find the plane which contains the line $x=-2+3t,y=4+2t,z=3-t$ and orthogonal to the plane $x-2y+z=5$

What I have thought is: a. the plane needs to be perpendicular to $(-2,4,3)+t(3,2,-1)$ which means that the normal vector of the plane (x,y,z) is perpendicular to the line or $(x,y,z)\times (3,2,-1)=0$
b. the plane needs to be orthogonal to the normal vector of the plane $x-2y+z=5$ which is $(x,y,z)\cdot (1,2,1)$

But I have 3 unknowns and 2 equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plane is perpendicular to the given plane, the given plane's normal vector is parallel to the plane you want to find, not perpendicular.  So the normal vector will be perpendicular to both (1,-2,1) and (3,2,-1), so it can be found using the cross product. With that and the given point of the line (-2,4,3), can get the equation of the plane.

Comment: So we get $3y+8z=36$?